# Will squeezing lemon juice on top of foods with ferrocyanide additive release hydrogen cyanide gas?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, toxicity

For example, will squeezing lemon juice on top of table salt with sodium ferrocyanide ($\ce{Na4[Fe(CN)6]}$) additive (E 535) release hydrogen cyanide gas?

Examples of ferrocyanide additives:

1. sodium ferrocyanide (E 535)
2. potassium ferrocyanide (E 536)
3. calcium ferrocyanide (E 538)

Comment: You can see [this video](https://youtu.be/bWNpO5vvhpk) at 2:02 for reference but seriously don't try this.

Comment: @NilayGhosh your video is irrelevant. This question is about hexacyanoferrate not sodium cyanide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The hexacyanidoferrate(II) complex is a very inert complex that does not undergo ligand exchange easily. This is somewhat exemplified by the harsh conditions alchemists used to synthesise hexacyanidoferrate(II), which included high temperatures and strong bases.

Furthermore, whatever amount of lemon juice you add the resulting acidity will be much less than in your stomach. If you swallow a cyanide source such as potassium cyanide, this will get protonated by your stomach acid to liberate hydrogen cyanide and potentially kill you. Food additives — especially approved ones — undergo various testing procedures to make sure that does not happen.

Comment: Yes, it has been demonstrated in [this video](https://youtu.be/bWNpO5vvhpk).

Comment: @NilayGhosh what you reference is totally misleading and irrelevant. Cody is playing with sodium cyanide. This question is about hexacyanoferrate salts which are totally different, behave totally differently and are far safer. It is easy to get HCN from sodium cyanide and almost impossible from hexacyanoferrate, which is why it is safe as a food additive.

Comment: Hexacyanoferrate(II) maybe?

Comment: Is the complex as stable with Fe(III) as with Fe(II)?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Hexacyanidoferrate(II) is actually *more* stable than hexacyanidoferrate(III) (which is an oxidising agent) due to the $\mathrm{(t_{2g})^6}$ state.

Comment: The iron(II) complex is more stable due to the fact that it is a low spin d6 compound with a high ligand field. It so happens that Prussian blue is a cyanide complex of iron which is a cation exchanger. Some forms of prussian blue can be used to remove cesium from people and animals. The normal dose for a Cs137 contaminated adult is 3 grams per day. But in extreme cases the dose can be increased to 30 grams a day. It is interesting that prussian blue varries a lot. I knew a man who used to work on the decontamination of farmyard animals he said he never had two batches which were the same.